# discord bot`s embed size

Tags: python, discord, bots, embed

how can I change the embed size? I found the width and height parameters in thumbnail, but I didn't understand if this is what I need.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHpV3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the size of an discord embed. It will automatically change it's size based on how much text there is, your discord client's zoom level and how big the images in it are.

Comment: that's pretty bad, there are channels that are spammed by those embed gifs, they take at least 15 lines each...